# Save matlab output in textfile

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, output

I have two vectors in matlab with n-entries, let us call them x and y.

Now I want to create a textfile that has the following structure: 
You have two columns(one for the x values and one for the y-values) and then I want to get:

```
    x(1)  y(1)
    x(2)  y(2)
    x(3)  y(3)
```

and so on.

does anybody here know how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can do this with `fprintf` in a for loop:

```
x=[0 1 2 3];
y=[4 5 6 7];
file = 'test.txt';
fh = fopen(file, 'wb');

if( length(x) ~= length(y) )
    error('x and y must have the same length');
end

for k = 1:length(x)
    fprintf(fh, '%f %f\n', x(k), y(k));
end

fclose(fh);
```

I assumed that you want to save floating point numbers. To save integer numbers use `%d` instead of `%f`.

Comment: today is fprintf-day? :o

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it without a loop. I have used a comma delimiter but if you try `help dlmwrite` you can see that you can easily turn it into a space for example.

```
x = [1; 2; 3]; 
y = [4; 5; 6];
dlmwrite('example.txt',[x y],'newline','pc')
```